# How to startAnimating the .gif every cell in the tableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview, gif

When I choose a cell in the tableview, the animation of .gif is stoped. how to solve it,who can give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

iOS does not support `gif` animaiton. You'll have to do it like so -

```
-(void)startImageViewAnimation
{
NSArray *animationImages = [NSarray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],nil];

UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
imageView.animationImages = animationImages ;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2;
imageView.animationDuration= 4.0;
[imageView startAnimating];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self
selector:@Selector(animationDone:)
userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
} 

-(void)animationDone:(NSTimer*)inTimer
{
[inTimer invalidate];
inTimer = nil;
NSLog(@"animationDone ");
}
```

Comment: Thank you,I must take the ImageViewAnimation in every cell, it mean that I must build so much NSTimer at the same time？

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the iPhone SDK doesnt do .gifs you have to to do the animation yourself via UIView

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage` doesn't have built-in support for animated GIFs, but it's pretty easy to use the Image I/O framework to load them.

[*Image I/O Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_intro/ikpg_intro.html)
[*Image I/O Reference Collection*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/ImageIORefCollection/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005102)

I have sample code that creates an animated `UIImage` from an animated GIF on github:

https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif